# Changing the value of one key/value pair in a json file with PHP

Tags: php, json

We have a simple json file that we use store data and are trying to figure out how to manipulate the value for one key and then save the new value in said json file using PHP.

The json file is basically:

```
{
  "stuff":"something",
  "more":"whatever",
  "name":"George",
  "about":"some string",
  "when":"tomorrow",
  many more key/value pairs
}
```

We want to get the 'about' string, append another string to it and then save the resultant longer string.  Getting the data and appending the additional string is not an issue.  It is saving the new string that has me stumped.

```
$data = json_decode($json);
foreach ($data as $key => $value) { 
  // look for about data
  if ($key == 'about') {
    $newstr = $value;
    $newstr .= ' extra string bits';
     
    // need to replace original $value with $newstr
    
  }
}

$newjson = json_encode($data);
```

The resultant json should be:

```
{
  "stuff":"something",
  "more":"whatever",
  "name":"George",
  "about":"some string extra string bits",
  "when":"tomorrow",
  many more key/value pairs
}
```

We are using the `foreach` as other values from the json file are being used in the PHP process, but if there is another better way to deal with the data retrieval and update portion, I am happy to separate the functions and welcome suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is:

```
$data = json_decode($json,true);
foreach ($data as $key => $value) { 
  // look for about data
  if ($key == 'about') {
    $newstr = $value;
    $newstr .= ' extra string bits';
    $data[$key] = $newstr;
  }
}

$newjson = json_encode($data);
```

Comment: I get an error: `Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array` pointing to the line for saving the newstr

Comment: Also, `json_encoode` doesn't exist

Comment: @Tom edited just now the answer

Comment: @Weber I was missing the 'true' in the json_decode

Comment: @brombeer - my bad, that typo wasn't in my test code, just in the abbreviated version I posted here.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `foreach`. When you `json_decode` your JSON you can simply set the objects new value by appending to it:

```
<?php
$json = '{
  "stuff":"something",
  "more":"whatever",
  "name":"George",
  "about":"some string",
  "when":"tomorrow"
}';
$data = json_decode($json);
$data->about .= ' extra string bits';
echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

will output:

```
{
    "stuff": "something",
    "more": "whatever",
    "name": "George",
    "about": "some string extra string bits",
    "when": "tomorrow"
}
```

Comment: That is a clean & easy solution.

Comment: I gave the accepted answer to Weber's response as it fit the `foreach` function that I was using in my code.  But yours is something that I am glad I have now learned for the future.  Thanks